# Android sample using H2

Tags: android, h2

I saw that you've done some tests on Android.
When I am trying to run my test with H2, I am getting FileNotFoundException.
I am trying to use use embedded mode and here is my code snippet:

```
    String url =  "jdbc:h2:~/myTestDB" + ";FILE_LOCK=FS" + ";PAGE_SIZE=1024"
    + ";CACHE_SIZE=8192";
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sa", "");
```

I have also tried:

```
    String url = "jdbc:h2:/data/data/" + "com.mydomain.MyApp"
            + "/data/myTestDB" + ";FILE_LOCK=FS" + ";PAGE_SIZE=1024"
            + ";CACHE_SIZE=8192";
```

but with no luck.

I've put myTest.h2.db in /assets  folder of my Android project.
If you can post your code sample that would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the problem could be, could you post the complete error message and stack trace? The 'official' documentation is here:

http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android

Comment: Thanks for sample. Now I see my mistake: I was supposed to use my app's package info in db path. 
It works now. But, I find H2 about about twice slower compared to SQLite. I am doing a simple select all query from 1000 row table. 
And I've tested on two different Android devices, HTC and Samsung.
My original problem still remains, SQlite is taking about a second to perform a simple select all query from 1000 row table. That is SLOW!

Does anyone know a fast SQLite driver for android ?

Comment: Yes, for simple queries I expect H2 to be slower than SQLite. Currently :-) I guess you need to solve the problem in a different way. One example is to not get all rows, another solution might be to store the data differently (keep all important data in one row or so).

Comment: This link is broken for me. Do you have a new one? I was really looking for for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was not very smart from me, I used a temporary link... I'm sorry I don't have that info any more. But I updated the link now.